# Sms Subscription using php code from my domain

Tags: php, sms

i want to send sms to those who have subscribed their number on my website. is there any way to send sms from my domain/website to those who have subscribed on my website?

Comment: can you please guide me

Comment: You may want to do some research on your own. People here will be more likely to help if you show some effort.

Comment: i have worked alot on it, but i am unable to get to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends where you are. You need go to buy the service from Service Providers. Such upside wireless or cell trust or others. There are some outside there. Search "sms service provider" on google. Most of them will provide you a api solution, you can use that to send out SMS message.

Comment: is there any way to get a api free of cost .. i live in pakistan

Comment: do some research on google "free sms pakistan", you can find some, but I am not so familiar of your country.